# Does anyone have an Atari breakout Deep Q-learning implementation that works?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, q-learning

I have been trying to use the implementation that is provided by Keras but get this error:

19 # Use the Baseline Atari environment because of Deepmind helper functions
---> 20 env = make_atari("BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4")
21 # Warp the frames, grey scale, stake four frame and scale to smaller ratio
22 env = wrap_deepmind(env, frame_stack=True, scale=True)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/envs/atari/environment.py in seed(self, seed)
185
186         if not hasattr(roms, self._game):
--> 187             raise error.Error(
188                 f'We're Unable to find the game "{self._game}". Note: Gym no longer distributes ROMs. '
189                 f"If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes you can download them "

Error: We're Unable to find the game "Breakout". Note: Gym no longer distributes ROMs. If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes you can download them via `pip install gym[accept-rom-license]`. Otherwise, you should try importing "Breakout" via the command `ale-import-roms`. If you believe this is a mistake perhaps your copy of "Breakout" is unsupported. To check if this is the case try providing the environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS=default::ImportWarning:ale_py.roms`. For more information see: https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-management

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I have tried many versions of Atari environments (the stuff that goes in the parenthesis here
on this line --> env = make_atari("BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4"). I have tried different versions etc. One interesting note is that when I used "ALE/Breakout-v5", I arrive at a different error.

NamespaceNotFound                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 81>()
79
80 # Use the Baseline Atari environment because of Deepmind helper functions
---> 81 env = make_atari("ALE/Breakout-v5")
82 # Warp the frames, grey scale, stake four frame and scale to smaller ratio
83 env = wrap_deepmind(env, frame_stack=True, scale=True)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in _check_namespace_exists(ns)
178     )
179
--> 180     raise error.NamespaceNotFound(f"Namespace {ns} not found. {suggestion_msg}")
181
182

NamespaceNotFound: Namespace ALE not found. Have you installed the proper package for ALE?

Ultimately, I am super lost, would really appreciate if anyone can link a functional version of Atari Breakout that I can run.